# Date sorting on a datatable with multiple formats

Tags: javascript, datatables

I am using a datatable that has a date column. I am trying to sort the table by Date Ascending but it doesn't seem to work. It is not sorting properly. It places July 30 above Mar 5. It is because I am using two different date formats (Marc 5, 2024 & Jul 30 - 31, 2024). Can you please help. Thanks. Here is my code -

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   
   var table = $('#test').DataTable({
  responsive: true,
  paging: false,
  lengthChange: false,
fixedHeader: true,
columnDefs: [
  {
    targets: 2,
    type: 'date',
  }
],
 
order:[[  2, 'asc' ]]
 
 } );
 
} );
```

```html
<table class="row-border stripe dt-right dataTable no-footer dtr-inline" id="test" style="width: 100%;"><thead text-align="left"><tr><th>Event</th><th>City, State</th><th>Date</th></tr></thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>My first event</th>
<td>Devnver,CO</th>
<td>Mar 4 - 7, 2024</th>
</tr>
 
<tr>
<td>My third event</th>
<td>Devnver,CO</th>
<td>Mar 5, 2024</th>
</tr>
 
<tr>
<td>My second event</th>
<td>Devnver,CO</th>
<td>Jul 30 - 31, 2024</th>
</tr>
 
<tr>
<td>My fourth event</th>
<td>Devnver,CO</th>
<td>Mar 5, 2024</th>
</tr>
```

Comment: `Mar 4 - 7, 2024` is not a valid date. It's a date range, but the date parser won't be able to parse it.

Comment: Your code snippet is incomplete and therefore throws an error when I try to run it: `"message": "ReferenceError: $ is not defined"`. Code snippets should be runnable (or, at least, they should show an error which is relevant to your question).

Comment: There are [many questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+datatables+date+sort) on Stack Overflow regarding date sorting in DataTables. I think at least some of those questions (and their answers) could be helpful for you. What have you researched? What have you tried?

Comment: There is also a section in the official DataTables [documentation](https://datatables.net/examples/datetime/index.html) which shows various date sorting examples. Do any of those help? If so, then how? If not, then how not? Don't be surprised if you end up needing to standardize the data in your date column.